# R Dataframe to list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to the below:

```
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
a  a1 a2 a3 a4
b  b1 b2
c  c1 c2 c3
```

I want to convert this to lists as below.

```
lista <- list(base="a", alts=c("a1","a2","a3","a4"))<br>
listb <- list(base="b", alts=c("b1","b2"))<br>
listb <- list(base="c", alts=c("c1","c2","c3"))
```

I have looked at solutions posted on here and tried some suggestions, but nothing works?1
Any help will be great! I am still new to R - Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `df` contains your data frame, you could try like this:

```
l <- lapply(as.data.frame(t(df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
            function(x) { 
              x <- unname(x) 
              list(base = x[1], alts = x[-1])
              })
names(l) <- paste0("list", df[, 1])
list2env(l, envir = .GlobalEnv)
lista
# $base
# [1] "a"
# 
# $alts
# [1] "a1" "a2" "a3" "a4"
```

Comment: Thanks lukeA, tested this on my live data and works 100%. I did a few tweaks to incorporate specific changes, but awesome thanks!